# Route Express.JS Post parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, post

I'm trying to get post parameters into a express.js code...

**[...].post(function(req, res){}** method doesn't work.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'vash');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.route('/a/:value').get(function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {title: req.params.value});
});

//app.route('/').post doesn t work.. the ide (WebStorm) can't find the .post method

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

The IDE (Webstorm) says that it can't find `.post()` method or function
Could you please help me ?
I'm using the last version of node.js.

[image]

Comment: Does it execute with Node.js? if yes, just ignore the warning of Webstorm.

Comment: @str Yes, it doesn't write any error, but i can't get the content... it just says " {} ". I did the post request via POSTMAN

Comment: Then please add the actual code and not just `app.route('/').post`.

Comment: @str Yes sure, i didn't know that there was this problem before cuz i didn't try as u said .